# Select onchange and custom text field value

Tags: javascript, jquery

i've select option below

```
<select id="order_package_id" class="form-control" name="order[package_id]">
  <option value="1">KJ01</option>
  <option value="2">KJ02</option>
  <option value="3">KJ03</option>
  <option value="4">KJ04</option>
  <option value="5">KJ DELUXE</option>
  <option value="6">KJO6</option>
</select>
```

and one text field with default value in hidden

```
<input id="order_discount_id" class="form-control" type="hidden" value="2" name="order[discount_id]">
```

My question is I want to make when select value is == 6, then the text field will change to value="3"

I've try with the jquery below but no luck

```
$('#order_package_id').change(function() {
  if($(this).val() == 6) {
    $('#order_discount_id').val() == 3;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the value to the `.val()` method. Without passing a value, `.val()` as a *getter*  returns the current value of the element. So what happens is you get the value and compare it against `3` using `==` operator. The code *effectively* doesn't do anything.

```
$('#order_discount_id').val(3);
```

For assignment the `=` operator should be used, but you can't use a value on the left side of assignment.

Edit: If the value should be `2` when the select's value is not `6`, you should add a `else` block to your code. Another option is using [conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
$('#order_package_id').change(function() {
    $('#order_discount_id').val( this.value == 6 ? "3" : "2" );
});
```

Comment: Your answer is correct. But then if i click the select value == 5, the text field value is still 3.. how to make it change back to value=2

Comment: Its working perfectly! Thank you so much for your help. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

To set the value, pass it to [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val) method:

```
$('#order_package_id').change(function() {
  if($(this).val() == 6) {
    $('#order_discount_id').val(3);
  }
});
```